# CSOM or JSOM code to update SharePoint 2013 user profile properties

Tags: sharepoint-addin

**CSOM or JSOM code to update SharePoint 2013 user profile properties.**

Requirement is to update the user profile properties from the provider hosted apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can not update user profile properties (except profile pic) using CSOM/JSOM. But `UserProfileService.asmx` can be used.

Check below links for further details.

1. [Update User Profile](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6899854-1a1c-42ef-8c4b-3852101f6a9e/updating-user-profile-properties-from-javascript-csom)
2. [Working with User Profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163800%28v=office.15%29.aspx)